# Rayrender only renders black image

Tags: r, raytracing

No matter which code I use from the documentation of the rayrender package, it only renders a black image?!?

Example:

```
library(rayrender)
#Generate the ground and add some objects
scene = generate_ground() %>%
  add_object(sphere(material = diffuse(color="#ff5555")))
render_scene(scene, parallel = TRUE, width = 800, height = 800, samples = 1000)
```

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same problem. Just a black square. So I downloaded the latest development version (`devtools::install_github("tylermorganwall/rayrender")`), updated packages, fixed a `clang` error with one installation (requiring reinstall `xcode` on my mac), and restarted R session...then it worked. This is a pretty cool package. I have no idea if my experience is helpful or not, but after going through that effort thought I would share. Good luck!

Comment: Packages that were updated: `cli, digest, ellipsis, fansi, pillar, pkgconfig, prettyunits, R6, raster, Rcpp, rlang, sp, vctrs`

Comment: @Ben: This worked, Thank you! Would you mind turning your comment into an answer? I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same problem on two separate instances with a black square (no 'progress' updates).

To get this working on each:

1. Installed the latest development version:

   ```
   devtools::install_github("tylermorganwall/rayrender")
   ```
2. Updated dependent packages. On Mac setup was: `cli, digest, ellipsis, fansi, pillar, pkgconfig, prettyunits, R6, raster, Rcpp, rlang, sp, vctrs`. On Windows setup was: `Rcpp, cli, fansi, pillar, rlang, sp, hms, perttyunits, R6, vctrs, digest`.
3. Restarted R session.

**Output**

[image: rayrender image]